# error when trying to run Arduino IDE on Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, arduino, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, arduino-ide

On my Raspberry Pi I have a clean Raspbian installation, on top of which I've installed openhab. I'd like to use the pi to program connected arduinos, so I've installed Arduino IDE. However when trying to run it I get this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.<clinit>(CommPortIdentifier.java:123)
    at processing.app.Editor.populateSerialMenu(Editor.java:962)
    at processing.app.Editor.buildToolsMenu(Editor.java:691)
    at processing.app.Editor.buildMenuBar(Editor.java:476)
    at processing.app.Editor.<init>(Editor.java:205)
    at processing.app.Base.handleOpen(Base.java:705)
    at processing.app.Base.handleOpen(Base.java:670)
    at processing.app.Base.handleNew(Base.java:566)
    at processing.app.Base.<init>(Base.java:306)
    at processing.app.Base.main(Base.java:195)
```

I have installed `librxtx-java` but the arduino IDE has still problems finding that library. Anybody came across similar issue?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is, that Arduino ships its own java installation.
When you start the Arduino-IDE, you just call a bash-script, that internally starts the (arduino-shipped) java to run the IDE in (this way, Arduino-IDE works on systems, were no java is installed at all).

Now that you have installed `librxtx-java` on your raspberry, you installed this lib into your systems-java-library directory. The Arduino-shipped java knows nothing about this library.

Give it a try to link (or copy) your `librxtx.jar` into your `<arduino_installation>/java/lib` folder.

(unfortunately I can not give it a try by myself, because I don't have a raspberry with me right now ;) )

Answer (score 0):

So the Arduino IDE probably didn't ship with it's own java version, as I did not find it directly in /usr/share/arduino folder, so I'm assuming it was using java that was already installed. After couple of tries I edited /usr/bin/arduino and added `-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni` to the java command. The full command looks like this now:

```
java -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni -Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel processing.app.Base "$@"
```

and the Arduino IDE started after that.

Comment: Oh okay, good to hear that you solved your problem. I took a look into my arduino-installation, which I didn't do via my package-mananger. I downloaded the arduino-1.8.8.tar file from arduino.cc and extracted it into `/opt/arduino`. When doing this, arduino does come with its own java-version.
Anyway, best of luck with your project :)